# Logstash grok filter doesn't add fields

Tags: logging, logstash-grok

So, I discovered the Grok Debugger where I successfully parsed my logs. But if I actually let the logs run through logstash, they show up in Kibana but without the extra fields.

My filter looks like this:

```
filter {
if [type] == "pat" {
    grok {
            match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time} %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} \[%{JAVACLASS:class}] %{GREEDYDATA:mydata}"
            }
    }
    date {
            match => [ "time" , "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS" ]
    }
}
}
```

And a typical log like this:

```
2016-03-08 15:26:45,111 INFO [ch.fhnw.imvs.pat.integration.adapter.vcs.GitAdapter] - gitweb.conf updated
```

But in Kibana I see the following but I should see my fields that I defined in the grok filter:

[Typical Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CB2ho.png)

Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

You should see that event in `filebeat-2016.03.08`  index.